# Should the 'infinite-loop' tag be purged?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Should the [infinite-loop](/questions/tagged/infinite-loop) tag be purged?

There are 242 questions tagged with this tag and it references a behavior that the questions are looking to correct, not a technology, framework, or other facet of a language on which a question can be reasonably categorized or grouped.

It seems to me that this tag is noise and adds nothing to a question.  It's too general to be a usable tag.

Similar tags include:

- [unresponsive](/questions/tagged/unresponsive)
- [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow)
- [exception](/questions/tagged/exception)

Comment: [tag:unresponsive], perhaps. [tag:infinite-loop], maybe; it's legitimate but probably abused. But what on earth is wrong with [tag:stackoverflow] and [tag:exception]?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People come to SO with their development problems.  Infinite loops are a subset of development problems.  There are probably people who would search this tag because they enjoy the suffering of others, or enjoy fixing infinite loops, or are looking for ways to debug infinite loops of their own.  Seems useful to me!

Same with stack overflows and exceptions, as Gilles notes.